# How to Drop Primary Key with Index?

Tags: mysql-workbench

I defind a table with some values as unordered.
Then, I alter table for set primary key to the table.
So, when I see the data of the table, Them display as a order list.
But after, Even I drop the the primary key and see the table data, It until display as order list.
But I need to get them as defined order.
But I have no Idea about what It has had.

Table data Defined order:

[image: Original table]

```
 alter table test add primary key(sno);
```

Data display After set primary key:

[image]

```
 alter table test drop primary key;
```

But After if  I remove primary key, the table data display  in same order.
I need to get data as like first. (defined order). because already I remove the primary key.

My expected out put after droping primary key:

[image: Expected out put]

Comment: Can you provide query using which query are you retrieving data?

Comment: select * from test;

Comment: You have to use order by srno desc

Comment: because Dropping the primary key will not change the physical order of the rows in the table

Comment: No sir I need to get table as Original table. I have some question about this. When I create a primary key, Is it automatically define a index no to the column ? and if it is, are we need to drop the index also to get the table as originall ?

Comment: When you create primary key, MySQL automatically create Unique index on that column.
When you drop primary key constraint, MySQL will automatically drop remove unique index on that particular column so you don't need to drop index explicitly.

Comment: So the why we unable to get data as same before (like order in original table)

Comment: no data physical order never change if you add and drop primary key

Comment: No, after I add primary key It not display record  as In the order in which I entered the data